# Test Driven Development with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

I'm new to testing and I need to add code to the class in the code file so that the tests created in the specification file pass.

I've written a comment in the code file where I think the tests should be written, but how do I write them so that they pass?

**My spec code looks like this:**

```
require "wad_TIM_00_gen"

module ImpossibleMachine
    # Input and output constants processed by subprocesses
    DOWN_ARROW = 1
    UP_ARROW = 2
    RIGHT_ARROW = 3
    REPEAT_ARROW = 4
    END_PROCESS = 5 
    START_CURRENT = 6

    # RSpec Tests 
    describe Game do
        describe "#start The impossible machine game" do
            before(:each) do
                @process = []
                @output = double('output').as_null_object
                @game = Game.new(@output)
            end

            it "sends a welcome message" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to the Impossible Machine!')
                @game.start
            end

            it "sends a starting message" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with('Starting game...')
                @game.start         
            end
        end
    end
```

**And my code file looks like this:**

```
# Main class module
module ImpossibleMachine
    # Input and output constants processed by subprocesses. MUST NOT change.
    DOWN_ARROW = 1
    UP_ARROW = 2
    RIGHT_ARROW = 3
    REPEAT_ARROW = 4
    END_PROCESS = 5 
    START_CURRENT = 6

    class Game
        attr_reader :process, :output
        attr_writer :process, :output

        def initialize(output)
            @output = output
            puts "[#{@output}]"
        end

        # I think the tests should be written here

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In `TDD`, you write tests first for the code you are going to write. As I see, you have already written the test, now you need to write the actual implementation in the place where you have commented. You need to implement `start` function, so that your tests pass.

You can read about `TDD` [here](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html), and about `TDD` with `RSpec` [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297).

Comment: Could you give me an example for the start function please?

Comment: First thing, you haven't written `RSpec` tests properly, you should be  matching the response of output of `start` function with the proposed output. And when you have written test for all possible outputs of this function, you can start implementing it.

I will recommend you to read this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby-for-newbies-testing-with-rspec--net-21297), which will help you in understanding these concepts.